# JS IPC; send messages from one tab to another?

Tags: javascript

For example with youtube center (a userscript) I can have a youtube video playing in one tab and I open another video the first one will pause. If I switch tabs and hit play the other will now pause. How does the userscript do this? I tried looking at [the source](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/blob/master/src/YouTubeCenter.user.js#L10533)

It appears to use a socket but it looks like socket is a [plain object](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/blob/master/src/YouTubeCenter.user.js#L3144). It says it mimics socket.io which I don't know either but I believe this one doesn't connect to a site while socket.io does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment says what it's happening. It's using localstorage (HTML5 functionality) to write and notify:

> /**
>         * A cross-window broadcast service built on top
>         * of the HTML5 localStorage API. The interface
>         * mimic socket.io in design.
>         *

The following lines set up the listeners.

```
if (identifier === 6) {
      session_addEventListener("storage", storageHandler);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      document.attachEvent('onstorage', storageHandler);
      ytcenter.unload(function(){
        document.detachEvent("storage", storageHandler);
      });
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('storage', storageHandler, false);
      ytcenter.unload(function(){
        window.removeEventListener("storage", storageHandler, false);
      });
    }
```

Clearly, there are listeners on both tabs such that every time you write/read to localstorage the other tab is notified.

So in short, no, the data doesn't go to a server. It simply writes to localstorage and relies on the browser to make available changes to localstorage across all tabs simultaneously.

You can read more about the storage event here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-event

Worth noting events aren't immediately available, only on activation of the Document (i.e. your events don't / might not get processed until the tab is active). I'd assume different browsers handle the 'activation' differently.

> Such a Document object is not necessarily fully active, but events fired on such objects are ignored by the event loop until the Document becomes fully active again.